# Replace function is not working in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace '?' with "'" but the question mark still remains. I am using below code to replace

```
df['Indication'] = df['Indication'].replace('?', '’')
```

The resulting column is given below:

```
Hodgkin?s Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression post-ASCT
```

But the output I want is the following:

```
Hodgkin's Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression post-ASCT
```

Comment: "but it is not working and giving some unwanted result" what is the unwanted result

Comment: @cs95 they provided that in the question, but i can edit it for clarity

Comment: @cs95 Hodgkinâ€™s Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression post-ASCT

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str.replace`:

```py
df["Indication"] = df["Indication"].str.replace("?", "'", regex=False)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                          Indication
0  Hodgkin's Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or ...
```

Comment: Hodgkinâ€™s Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression post-ASCT